# Como paginar usando o Flask e retornar em Json?

Tags: python, json, paginação, flask, neo4j

Preciso fazer uma consulta ao banco (neo4j) e retornar um json, porém como a resposta é muito grande preciso paginar. Já olhei muito aqui no stack, porém a maioria das respostas usam o método de paginação do sqlalchemy ou retornam um render template com o objeto Pagination, e não é isso que eu preciso. Tem alguma forma de retornar isso em json ou de ao menos converter esse Pagination para json?

Answer (score -2):

Qualquer objeto pode ser convertido para JSON. Existe o método jsonify.

```
from flask import jsonify

return jsonify(Pagination)
```